Reflection api in any point studio
Can we use Java reflection to modify the behavior of error.muleMessage to return a custom message In any-point Studio?
if so can anyone help me with java reflection to mock munit that return custom error.muleMessage.And is it safe to use reflection for munit. My Munit version is 2.3.0 and Mule version is 4.3.0

It would almost certainly the wrong thing to do. You should not be using error.muleMessage in the first place, because it is an internal implementation variable that was not meant to be used in Mule applications. The documented variable is error.errorMessage. See the documentation for other documented variables. I suggest to open a new question explaining the issue that you are trying to resolve using reflection instead of trying to hack a solution that will not work in the long term.
Even if it works in Mule 4.3 it will stop working in Mule 4.6 which limited the access to internal classes:

Mule runtime classes are now modularized per the Java module system introduced back in Java 9 (also known as JPMS or Project Jigsaw). Reflective introspection of Mule runtime classes is now limited. To maintain backward compatibility, reflective access to classes defined within the scope of your applications and domains remains open to access.

Also Mule 4.3 will be end of life in March 2025. It is recommended to migrate a version that supports newer versions of Java. Mule 4.6 supports JDK 17 optionally, and Mule 4.9 will only support JDK 17. See Mule Runtime Release Cadence Support.
