How to Use Java Reflection in MUnit to Modify `error.muleMessage` in Mule 4?
I am trying to create an MUnit test for a flow that uses the error.muleMessage variable. If it's error.errorMessage, I can modify the content by creating a custom exception and providing a description, but unfortunately, I need to set a variable for error.muleMessage, and there isn't any documentation available that I can use.
I can create an error with a custom description using the format #[java!java::lang::Exception::new('custom error with status code 422')], but it always sets the value in error.description. I need to set that value in error.muleMessage.
Any ideas on how to use Java reflection to modify the behavior of error.muleMessage to return a custom message in Anypoint Studio? If so, can anyone help me with using Java reflection to mock an MUnit test that returns a custom error.muleMessage? Also, is it safe to use reflection for MUnit? My MUnit version is 2.3.0 and Mule version is 4.3.0
I tried creating a subflow in MUnit to mock the main flow, expecting it to replicate the exact issue, but it seems it doesn't set the value for error.muleMessage.

You already asked the same question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78922988/reflection-api-in-any-point-studio. Avoid duplicating questions.
